# Would a strong diamagnetic material exhibit inductance?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

Do metals with the property of strong diamagnetism also exhibit inductance? 
Would a fluctuating magnetic field induce a weaker current in a strongly diamagnetic metal as compared against a ferromagnetic/paramagnetic metal?

I remember reading metal-detectors are based upon the property of inductance. So if a metal detector were to hover over a silver ingot/plate, would it succeed or fail?

Comment: From what kind of metals are transformer windings made? Are that metals ferro/diamagnetic? Is there any metal which is not basically diamagnetic?

Comment: Georg, Good call - as far as i know transformer windings are usually copper/silver i.e. strongly diamagnetic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Most diamagnets have a very small magnetic susceptibility, of the order
of $-10^{-5}$. Thus I would not expect any significant effect of their
susceptibility on the induced eddy currents.

One exception are the superconductors. In some sense they can be
considered like perfect diamagnets ($\chi = -1$). If you apply a field
on a superconductor you will induce a significant current on its
surface, enough to screen the field inside the superconductor (this is
the [Meissner effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect)).